# Как передать в Mysql <>нескольким числам?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно обновить все поля mark на 0, кроме $checkboxId (5,6 и тд которые приходят). `<>` работает только с 1 числом. Если `<>in(".$checkboxId.")` так не работает. Как правильно запрос тогда сделать? ($mark = 0, $checkboxId = нескольким числам)
`"UPDATE task_list SET mark = '$mark' WHERE id <> (".$checkboxId.")";`
Получается у меня будет обновляются все поля на 0 кроме выбранных,как сделать, что бы выбранные получали значение 1? Так наверно не получится
Нельзя такой запрос как то сделать?)
`"UPDATE task_list SET mark = '$mark' WHERE id NOT IN(".$checkboxId.") SET mark = '1' WHERE id in(".$checkboxId.")";`
**Придумал решение, но думаю это как то тупо, но работает. Можно ли как то в один запрос переделать?**

```html
$q = "UPDATE task_list 
              SET mark = '0' 
              WHERE id NOT IN(".$checkboxId.")";
        $this->query($q);
        $q = "UPDATE task_list 
              SET mark = '1' 
              WHERE id IN(".$checkboxId.")";
        $this->query($q);
```

Comment: `NOT IN (......`

Comment: Спасибо, у меня еще чуток условие не правильное. Обновляет на 0 все кроме не выбранных. Но когда я выбираю они не добавляются в бд как 1. Нужно будет что то придумать

Comment: покажите что у Вас в $checkboxId, несколько вариантов и, желательно именно var_dump

Answer (score -1):

В mysql `!=, <>` это операторы сравнения. Также в mysql есть логические [операторы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html). В вашем случае можно использовать логический оператор `AND`:

**Вариант №1:**

```
...WHERE id!='5' AND id!='6';
```

**Вариант №2:**

```
...WHERE id<>'5' AND id<>'6';


$checkboxId_1=5;
$checkboxId_2=6;
```

Надежный способ будет "очистить все" а затем выставить 1 тем которым нужно.

**Первый запрос (делаем всем 0):**

```
 "UPDATE task_list SET mark = '0' WHERE id >'0' ";
```

**Второй запрос (ставим 1 по айдишникам):**

```
"UPDATE task_list SET mark = '$mark' WHERE id <> (".$checkboxId_1.") AND id <> (".$checkboxId_2.") ";
```

Comment: Как мне в запросы дописать, что бы $checkboxId получали значение 1? То есть `"UPDATE task_list SET mark = '$mark' WHERE id <> (".$checkboxId.")";` и нужно добавить в запрос, что бы checkboxId  поля mark были = 1. Получается у меня не выбранные поля получают 0, а выбранные $checkboxId должны получить 1

Answer (score -1):

Нужно использовать связку

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox_name" value="0"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" value="1"/>
```

Тогда вам всегда буде приходить полный список, что изменилось на 1, а что на  0 (так как checkbox не приходит в реквесте, если он не checked => будет приходить hidden value, но а если checked => то значение checkbox)